# open configuration after app installation

Tags: java, android

How can I open it right after the app is installed on android?
I tried to access this setting on installation but I get a message that this app is not yet installed.
"the app was not found in the list of installed apps"

startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS));

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by getting the package name.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
i.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
startActivity(i);
```